Unknown symbols in perf report output
I have one virtual machine running on QEMU/KVM and I'm trying to profile QEMU to investigate performance related issues. I have it compiled on a Linux system with debug symbols -
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --target-list=x86_64-softmmu --enable-debug-info
make -j`nproc`

Running perf on the QEMU process does list most of the symbols, but some are showing up as unknown -
perf record -g --quiet -p $qemu_pid -o perf.out -F 99 -- sleep 10 &
perf report -
+   74.83%     0.00%  worker           [kernel.kallsyms]        [k] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe                                                                                   ◆
+   74.83%     0.00%  worker           [kernel.kallsyms]        [k] do_syscall_64                                                                                                    ▒
-   72.37%     0.00%  worker           [unknown]                [k] 0000000000000000                                                                                                 ▒
   - 0                                                                                                                                                                               ▒
      - 32.87% 0x6a00000002                                                                                                                                                          ▒
         + __libc_pwrite                                                                                                                                                             ▒
      - 21.18% 0xb00000001                                                                                                                                                           ▒
           __libc_pread                                                                                                                                                              ▒
           entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe                                                                                                                                            ▒
         + do_syscall_64                                                                                                                                                             ▒
      + 13.43% pwritev64                                                                                                                                                             ▒
      + 4.50% fdatasync                                                                                                                                                              ▒
+   44.75%     0.00%  worker           [kernel.kallsyms]        [k] ext4_file_write_iter                                                                                             ▒
+   44.71%     0.00%  worker           [kernel.kallsyms]        [k] ext4_buffered_write_iter                                                                                         ▒
+   33.36%     0.00%  worker           [kernel.kallsyms]        [k] vfs_write                                                                                                        ▒
+   32.87%     0.00%  worker           [unknown]                [k] 0x0000006a00000002                                                                                               ▒
+   32.87%     0.00%  worker           libc.so.6                [.] __libc_pwrite                                                                                                    ▒
+   32.74%     0.00%  worker           [kernel.kallsyms]        [k] __x64_sys_pwrite64                                                                                               ▒
+   31.48%     0.00%  worker           [kernel.kallsyms]        [k] new_sync_write                                                                                                   ▒
+   31.17%     0.00%  worker           [kernel.kallsyms]        [k] generic_perform_write                                                                                            ▒
+   21.27%     0.00%  worker           libc.so.6                [.] __libc_pread                                                                                                     ▒
+   21.22%     0.00%  worker           [kernel.kallsyms]        [k] ext4_file_read_iter                                                                                              ▒
+   21.22%     0.00%  worker           [kernel.kallsyms]        [k] generic_file_read_iter                                                                                           ▒
+   21.22%     0.37%  worker           [kernel.kallsyms]        [k] filemap_read                                                                                                     ▒
+   21.18%     0.00%  worker           [unknown]                [k] 0x0000000b00000001

...etc
Is there a way to fix the unknown symbols to generate a complete perf report? Or any way to know which library these symbols may belong to, so that it can be compiled with debug symbols?
QEMU version -
user@host:~$ /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 --version
QEMU emulator version 6.2.0 (Debian 1:6.2+dfsg-2ubuntu6.16)
Copyright (c) 2003-2021 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers


You don't give your QEMU command line or version. My guess is that time is time spent executing guest code, either in the TCG JITted code if you're using emulation, or else spent executing the guest code directly under KVM if you're using that.

@PeterMaydell My apologies for not including the QEMU version. I have edited the question to include the same. I'm using QEMU with KVM.

QEMU documentation does not mention the flags to enable for building a non-stripped binary.
Running ./configure -h will list all the available options and after some investigation, I was able to build the binary with debug symbols.
./configure --enable-debug-tcg --enable-debug-info --enable-debug --disable-strip --target-list=x86_64-softmmu --enable-kvm --extra-cflags="-g3" --extra-ldflags="-g3"

